# Application installed by NPM (eg File C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1) cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg, angular10

When running commands installed by npm (i.e. yarn, ng, etc.), I receive the following error:

```
File C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\<application> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
```

where <application> is one of the commands installed by npm (i.e. yarn, ng, etc.)

How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I just try this command in VS terminal(PowerShell) and my problem has been solved

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser**

note : don't change **CurrentUser** to your username

 **edit** : you can follow this link for changing the visual studio code terminal to cmd.exe instead of PowerShell and it will work without any security issues. https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/02/vs-code-integrated-terminal-powershell-default-change-to-cmd/

Comment: I had an issue with  calling `yarn` from my powershell term in Visual Studio Code.  Don't change "CurrentUser" to your username.

Comment: This worked for me to solve the ERROR: <br> \
```truffle : File C:\Users\Rain - Blockchain\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is       
disabled on this system.```

I was trying deploying contract on rospten testnet.

Comment: why you bypass the security, I hope you know the behavior of the command

Comment: for me it works in powershell not cmd

Comment: This does not work in `CMD`. it will work with  `PowerShell`  (Admin). 
Hope this will help to someone :-)

Comment: @SaadAbbasi thanks a lot man. This comment is very crucial to run this command.